# PMD rule God Class - understanding the metrics

Tags: java, pmd

We are using the source code analyzer PMD in our Java project. I am trying to resolve the reported issues and I am currently struggling with the `GodClass` rule. I know that the idea is not to create huge classes.

However, I don't like the word "huge" because it's too vague. Can anybody explain how the metrics of this rule works? The report says e.g.

`Possible God class (WMC=47, ATFD=11, TCC=0.06315789473684211)`

What do all these numbers mean? Does anybody know the formula that decides whether a particular class is huge or not?

Javadoc to this rule states

> The rule uses the detection strategy described in [1]. The violations are reported against the entire class. [1] Lanza. Object-Oriented Metrics in Practice. Page 80.

Well, I don't wont to order some book just because of its page 80.

Btw. is there a way to configure such rule, i.e. change its parameters?

Thanks for explanation.

Comment: Amazon lets you look inside that book (!)

Comment: I admit that I am not familiar with Amazon Look inside. I have tried it just now. It seems that I cannot look inside the full version of this particular book. Only the chapter Introduction is available.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- WMC = Weighted Methods Count
- ATFD = Access To Foreign Data
- TCC = Tight Class Cohesion

Baselines seems to be defined as constant values. If you would like to know more, you can find the implementation [here](https://github.com/pmd/pmd/blob/master/pmd-java/src/main/java/net/sourceforge/pmd/lang/java/rule/design/GodClassRule.java). (A little older code, but it is all in one place [here](https://pmd.github.io/pmd-5.8.1/pmd-java/xref/net/sourceforge/pmd/lang/java/rule/design/GodClassRule.html).)

Comment: looks like the link is broken.

Answer (score 15):

WMC stands for Weighted Methods Count or Weighted Method per Class.  The WMC metric is defined as the sum of complexities of all methods declared in a class. This metric is a good indicator how much effort will be necessary to maintain and develop a particular class.

ATFD stands for Access to Foreign Data.  This metric represents the number of external classes from which a given class accesses attributes, directly or via accessor-methods.

TCC stands for Tight Class Cohesion.  TCC is the relative number of methods directly connected via accesses of attributes.

The [code](https://github.com/pmd/pmd/blob/master/pmd-java/src/main/java/net/sourceforge/pmd/lang/java/rule/design/GodClassRule.java) triggers a violation if WMC >= 47 and ATFD > 5 and TCC < 1/3.

You can read about the God class on [page 55](https://books.google.com/books?id=gdLbgnaMaa0C&pg=PA55#v=onepage&q&f=false) in Object-Oriented Metrics in Practice (and you do not have to buy the book to just read 1 page).  You can also read the PMD [documentation](https://pmd.github.io/pmd-5.8.1/pmd-java/rules/java/design.html#GodClass).